# Convert Function to a Class Python, Beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Hi I am attempting to write my first Class by converting this function into a class.

# My Function

```
def left_click_first_Thompson(x, y, clicks=17):
    SetCursorPos(x, y)
    for i in range(clicks):
        mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0, 0)

def left_click_M1A1_Thompson(x, y, clicks=2):
    SetCursorPos(x, y)
    for i in range(clicks):
        mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

"""Me Attempting to Turn it into a Class """

```
class AimMouse(object):

    # The Constructor to Instantiate the Objects
    def __init__(self, x, y, clicks):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.clicks = clicks

    def left_click_first_Thompson(self, x, y, clicks=17):
        SetCursorPos(x, y)
        for i in range(clicks):
            mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0, 0)

    def left_click_M1A1_Thompson(self, x, y, clicks=2):
        SetCursorPos(x, y)
        for i in range(clicks):
            mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Can I please get someone to proof read and correct ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Since I just understood your idea now, here is some code to put you on the right track:

```
import ctypes

SetCursorPos = ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos
mouse_event = ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event

class Aimer:
    def __init__(self, clicks):
        self.clicks = clicks 

    def handle_click(self, x, y):
        SetCursorPos(x, y)
        for i in range(self.clicks):
            mouse_event(2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0, 0)

thompsonAimer = Aimer(clicks=17) 
m1a1Aimer = Aimer(clicks=2)
```

Your code is correct, but you do not explain your motivation to turn this into a class.

A class is often used when the various functions need to share some state. For instance, let's say we want to fix the number of clicks for all function calls, and the functions do not receive such an argument. You set `self.clicks = clicks` in the constructor, and then in `left_click...` instead of clicks you use `self.clicks`.

The way it is now, it is pointless to store `self.x`, `self.y` and `self.clicks` because they are not being used.

If you are a beginner, I would not recommend focusing on classes, though it is good to have an idea of how they work.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, the reason I wish to use a class, is because I have many functions with various click amounts I wish to add to the code.  In a way to neaten up the Code I  was hoping to store these various functions with different click amounts as a class and then to import this class to beaten up the main Code file.

Comment: Still, unless these functions share some data, there is no point in using a class. I would rather have a bunch of functions. At least that's the pattern I usually go by.

Comment: Thanks for your input yes all functions share the same data: x, y and clicks but will have different values.  My understanding is that a class is a template for objects this would be recommended in this case ??

Comment: You might have a misunderstanding. By "sharing data" I mean that *values* will be shared. For instance, if you want some configuration for the clicker class, it makes sense to make it into a class and process the configuration on construction. In your case, however, the x, y, and clicks are different for each click, so they are not shared.

Comment: So it would make sense to cull the x and y in the functions and have static self.clicks values in each functions in the class ? If it’s to much to answer I will go away and read up more ...

Comment: sorry, it's not too much to answer, but the answer is "it depends what you want/need" :) Would the value of clicks ever be reused?

Comment: Regardless thanks for your time! Yes the value of clicks is reused per weapon hence it’s a a static value hence, when weapon is changed we use a different method from the class with the statically assigned “clicks” value.  I will go off and learn thanks again

Comment: Wait, now I understand what you are trying to do! See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for responding back, we are close I just cannot figure out how to call it properly..  aim_mouse.thompsonAimer.handle_click(x, y) find the positions perfectly, however Its not clicking....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158767/discussion-between-recencyeffect-and-gavin-jones).